# Difference b/w Mockito,junit and TestNG

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I am new to unit testing so please can anybody tell me difference b/w Mockito and **TestNG**. And which tool will be suitable for unit testing.

Comment: Removed unwanted text and format changes

Answer (score 0):

Both tools are suitable for unit testing and you can use them together. TestNG is similar to JUnit but introducing some new functionalities, and Mockito allows you to add mock objects to your tests.